# how to auto time out a website after certain time without the will of viewer?

Tags: web

I am currently working on a website and i need to auto close the page after some interval 
e.g after 5 minutes the website closes itself automatically.

Comment: What would be the use case for this? Most websites simply log out inactive users by letting their session expire. Autoclosing a page/window can be pretty annoying, especially if the user hasn't deliberately triggered the close action (e.g. click something, take focus away from the page, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout('self.close();',30000);

Comment: thanks it worked for 30 seconds only
can't minutes be used in place of miliseconds

Comment: no, but you can use minutes converting to milisec. like 1min=60000